# arcpy.Mapping.UpdateLayer not working

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

The layer to be updated (`ul`) does not get applied with the style from the source layer (`sl`) and the code executes without throwing any error.

```py
import os
import csv
import arcpy
#Set home geodatabase.
arcpy.env.workspace =  "\ArcGIS\Python_test"
#Set shapefile path to variable.
PointFile = "\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_data.csv"
#Import well location shapefile template CSV.
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(PointFile)
#Make well location event layer.
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management("Well_data_View", "Easting", "Northing", 'Well_plot_EventLayer', 'WGS 1984 UTM Zone 43N')
#Convert temporary event layer to feature class for saving.
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("Well_plot_EventLayer", "\ArcGIS\Python_test", 'Well_plot')
#Delete event layer.
arcpy.Delete_management("Well_plot_EventLayer")
#Reference the map document (.mxd).
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Python_workspace.mxd")
#Reference dataframe.
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
#Reference layer to be updated and reference layer.
ul = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_plot.lyr")
sl = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_SR.lyr")
#Update the layer. THIS DOES NOT WORK!!
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, ul, sl)
```

Comment: You appear not to have saved your MXD.

Comment: I have saved my .mxd hence I am able to reference its path on my hard disk to a variable in my code.

Comment: But you have not saved it at the end of your code which means that when you check it the state of your MXD is as before you ran it.

Comment: ie, add `mxd.save()` to the end of the script.

Comment: Additionally, `UpdateLayer()` is for layers in a map document, not layers in a layer file.  You appear to be updating a layer from a layer file, not a layer in the map.  Should `ul` actually be defined something like, `ul = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Well Plot", df)[0]` ?  (You can save the map layer back to a .lyr file afterwards if that is what you actually want.)  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of wherher you are attempting to change a layer in a .mxd map document, or you are attempting to update a layer in a .lyr file, there are two problems with your code:

1. The script doesn't save the changes (as commented by @PolyGeo).  You need to either save the map document or overwrite the layer file.
2. `UpdateLayer()` is for layers in a map document, not layers in a layer file. You appear to be updating a layer from a layer file, not a layer in the map. `ul` should be defined something more like:

`ul = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Well Plot", df)[0]`

(Change "Well Plot" to whatever the layer is actually named in the MXD.)

See: [arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer()](http://UpdateLayer()%20is%20for%20layers%20in%20a%20map%20document,%20not%20layers%20in%20a%20layer%20file.%20You%20appear%20to%20be%20updating%20a%20layer%20from%20a%20layer%20file,%20not%20a%20layer%20in%20the%20map.%20Should%20ul%20actually%20be%20defined%20something%20like,%20ul%20=%20arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,%20%22Well%20Plot%22,%20df)[0]%20?%20(You%20can%20save%20the%20map%20layer%20back%20to%20a%20.lyr%20file%20afterwards%20if%20that%20is%20what%20you%20actually%20want.)%20See:%20desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/%E2%80%A6)

So the last few lines of your code should be something more like:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Python_workspace.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
ul = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Well Plot", df)[0]
sl = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_SR.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, ul, sl)
mxd.save()
```

( If you want to actually overwrite a .lyr file, and not save the mxd, then don't add the `mxd.save()`, but instead you can save the map layer back to a .lyr file using:  [arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/save-to-layer-file.htm) )

Comment: What I have done is created and saved my mxd (Python_test.mxd), then, through code created a point shapefile (Well_plot) from the .csv file I have on my disk. This Well_plot shapefile is a layer created in the map document and not saved/exported; I have a .lyr file in the project home folder (Well_SR) which I want to use as a style template for Well_plot. Well_SR.lyr has not been added to the map and is present only in the project home folder. So in short, I ain't overwriting a layer file, just re-formatting a map layer (Well_plot). I hope this clarifies your doubts @Son of a Beach.

Comment: The line:
ul = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_plot.lyr")
was added initially by me because after creating Well_plot I exported it as a .lyr file manually from the TOC to my home folder because I felt the attributes for UpdateLayer need to be layer files specifically. But then I ditched that path because it seemed unnecessary after going though the updates you sugested to my code.

Comment: I hope it has helped?

Comment: I defined variable 'ul' as `ul = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0]` because it is present as a layer in the map document only. I get the following error - 

`Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1889, in UpdateLayer
    assert isinstance(source_layer, Layer)
AssertionError`

Comment: Looks like some problem with the source layer, or something else in the UpdateLayer call.  You should post a new question for this.

Comment: Adding a `mxd.save()` helped. The parent layer style now get applied to the new layer successfully. Thank you @PolyGeo and @Son of a Beach